# Problem with msiexec and pssession in a script

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I am attempting to write a powershell script which installs an .msi package. It takes user's input (client's IP and username) then creates a new PSSession and pulls the file from network drive.

```
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName $destination -Credential <xxxxxx>
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {msiexec /i "\\CLOUD_IP\road-to\msi-location\msi_to_install.msi"}
```

This is the main problem with the script. Once the script finishes, the installation prompts on my PC, not the client's, but it still stays in session. Until I exit the session either manually or via script.

Everything works as intended when I enter those two lines manually into powershell prompt.

I tried putting a *Start-Sleep* inbetween the two lines, since it takes a tad bit time for the *Enter-PSSession*, but that did nothing.

*$destination* is the user's IP input, which works as *-ComputerName* aswell, since *Get-PSSession* shows the IP as the computer name.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $destination -Credential <xxxxxx> -ScriptBlock {msiexec /i "\\CLOUD_IP\road-to\msi-location\msi_to_install.msi" /qn /quiet /norestart}
```

Comment: Thanks for the swift answer, but that didn't work. Now the installer doesn't prompt at all. Not on my PC or the client PC.

I also added in couple lines that copied the package from my PC to the client's and that works just well so the issue isn't connectivity.

Comment: If you don't want the msi to run silently, remove the `/qn /quiet /norestart` options

Comment: Right, forgot to mention that I didn't use /qn /quiet or /norestart. Regardless, its a service so it should be visible from services.msc, but it is not. Also, your suggestion doesn't work even if I typed it in manually. I tried `write-host "Invoke-Command -ComputerName $destination -Credential <xxxxxx> -ScriptBlock {msiexec /i "\\CLOUD_IP\road-to\msi-location\msi_to_install.msi"}` just to see if the variables give a correct answer from the user input, which it did. The command should be correct.